# Pointers to the same location

Tags: c, pointers

I have been struggling with this for quite some time now.

While copying array of strings like in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf ("%d: %s @ %p \n",i,argv[i],argv[i]);
    }

    char* states[7];                                                        

    for (i = 0; i <argc; i++)
    {
        states[i] = argv[i];      // line 36
        printf ( "State no.%d: %s @ %p \n", i ,states[i],&states[i]);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

I obtain the following output:

> OUTPUT:
>   0: ./ex1 @ 0x7fff651da366
>   State no.0: ./ex1 @ 0x7fff651d94d0

Shouldn't both the addresses in the output be the same as on line 36 of the code I am making both the pointers point to the same address?

Comment: Please don't number lines of code. Copy-pasting a line to indicate which one in an answer is quick. Removing numbers that prevent from compiling to reproduce the problem is slow.

Comment: Both pointers point to the same place, that is, pointer values are the same. Their addresses are still different.

Answer (score 7):

The expression `&states[i]` gives you the address of where `states[i]` is in memory, and not where it's pointing. Drop the address-of operator to fix the problem.